# Reflected radiation from increased CO2 : how was this calculated

Tags: climate-change, climate

The IPCC claims that the reflected radiation from incresaed CO<sub>2</sub> heats the Earth at a rate of 5 W m<sup>-2</sup>. How did the contributing researchers came out with that result?

Comment: It would be a better question if there was some sort of links or references to the claims (from the IPCC) you are pointing at

Comment: Welcome. And where does it claim so ?

Comment: The wiki [Greenhouse effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_effect) explains how this works. The [IPCC report](https://www.ipcc.ch/site/assets/uploads/2018/02/WG1AR5_Chapter08_FINAL.pdf) has more detail. Too much to put in an Answer.

Comment: We know about the greenhouse effect. But we can't answer the question without knowing the source for the figure. It might be too low, meanwhile.